# How to show function args at flowchart?

Tags: flowchart

The following is like reverse-engineering for code understanding. So here is the function:

```
void deleteTask(TaskPtr& head, const char* fullName)
{
    TaskPtr current, nodeToDelete;
    if(strcmp(head->fullName, fullName) == 0)
    {
        current = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete(current->address);
        delete(current);
        return;
    }

    for(current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next)
    {
        if(strcmp(current->next->fullName, fullName) == 0)
        {
            nodeToDelete = current->next;
            current->next = nodeToDelete->next;
            delete(nodeToDelete->address);
            delete(nodeToDelete);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

How to show `head` and `fullName` args at flowchart (block diagram)?

Comment: May be this will help: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/75895/196269 Good Luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the variant of mentioning args within separate block that is connected with begin block by dot line. Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard for showing arguments on flowcharts. However, in UML, you could show arguments on UML Sequence Diagram on the directed arrow, as in some examples here: [UML Sequence Diagrams](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/3101.html). Arguments are shown on the diagram as: `method_name(arg1, arg2, ..., argn)`.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced same problem before
i draw my flow chart by looking this example
i am not sure it is officially valid flowchart or not but it doesn't matter right because the point is to convey your idea to reader clearly.

[Flow chart example](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/182472/drawing-flowchart-for-function-calculate-a-number-in-the-fibonacci-series)

Both answers are reasonable but second is more appropriate for flowchart drawing.

Comment: link is dead as of 2016

Comment: Indeed :) I guess you can find sth similar in following website: http://cssimplified.com/c-programming/design-an-algorithm-draw-a-corresponding-flow-chart-and-write-a-program-in-c-to-print-the-fibonacci-series-10m-jun2006